# Reactjs React.memo doesnt memorized const function

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component

React.memo doest work when I use them like that:
In this case Hello component is memo.

```
...
const Item=() =>{
    return <Hello />
}
...
```

But if I use like that it works:

```
...
<Hello />
...
```

How can I use React.memo as a const function?

This is the [sample code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-mwd9sq)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this in two ways for the `Item` component:-

```
const Item=useCallback(() =>{
        return <Hello/>
    },[])
```

OR

Keep the `Item` function as it is and just instead of declaring it as a component in JSX like `<Item/>`, call the function like `Item()`.

Replace your `<Item/>` declaration with `{Item()}`.

Comment: Please, can you provide example how to cal Item() as a function in JSX?

Comment: Added to my answer.